# Inspect function in RStudio

Tags: r

Is there a CRAN package that includes the inspect function ? Arules and TM are installed, but I am still getting an error message any time I have to type in "inspect" that says "could not function inspect"

Comment: Works for me. The first example in `?arules::inspect` worked with no errors.

Comment: did you call `library(arules)` as well as installing it?

Comment: A good way to find all the packages that contain a function name: https://www.rdocumentation.org/search?q=inspect